# Apache SVN problem error 403 when used without slash

Tags: svn, apache2, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I have SVN DAV setup in my Apache config now (after a lot of time trying to figure out how to set up ssl)

anyway, it seems to work now if I use the following config:

```
<Location /svn/>
        DAV svn
        SVNListParentPath on
        SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn/repos/
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /usr/local/svn/.svn-policy-file
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/svn/.svn-auth-file
        DirectorySlash on
        Satisfy Any
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

AND if I type the slash into web browser when i make the request:

http://remotehost/svn/  <- cool, no problems

but if I remove the trailing slash in the location

```
<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNListParentPath on
        SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn/repos/
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /usr/local/svn/.svn-policy-file
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/svn/.svn-auth-file
        DirectorySlash on
        Satisfy Any
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I got an error 403 forbidden whether I add the slash at the end or not:

http://remotehost/svn <- doesn't work
http://remotehost/svn/ <- doesn't work

I'm pretty new to apache configs so if anyone could help me with clear explanations regarding what I might need to do to fix it, it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple repositories? If not, why are you using `SVNParentPath`? use `SVNPath`. See the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic) for details.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple repositories, one per project.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my configuration to see the difference:

```
<Location /src>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /opt/cm/svn_repos
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "MFX Repository"
....
```

There's your problem! You have a slash after the directory name in `SVNParentPath`.

Remove the ending slash on directory names, and that should solve your issues.

Comment: Got around to trying, it, doesn't work, if I remove the slash I get a permissions error.